# Open URL from Marker, Android Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a marker with HTML content, that actually has 2 anchors URL inside it, i already draw it on the GoogleMap as the demo library explains.

The issue is how can i click on the url inside the marker, the Google Maps API V2 only let me set OnInfoWindowClickListener where i only recieve the Marker but there is no way to get the actual click on the URL.

Implementing the InfoWindowsAdapter.getInfoWindow(Marker) method with a listener to the inflated view, is just being ignored (the listener part is never called, looks like it only get the whole globe, not the URL).

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is how can i click on the url inside the marker

According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker), you can't:

> Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as described in the section below.